# SoundCloud API Error Code 429 out of nowhere

Tags: soundcloud

I have an app running on SoundCloud's PHP API.
Today when I or anyone else tries to authorize the app, the callback returns `Error Code 429`, which I found meant too many requests. After waiting about an hour it works again for a few minutes.

The app has always had the same amount of users, and today authorizing seems to no longer work 80% of the time.

I also tried registering a new app and the same problems occured.

Is there an issue on SoundCloud's side? Is there anything I can do to fix this?